# Error with count of docs where criteria applies to embedded array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a mongoDB collection called Assignments, which have multiple bids (embedded arrays). When one of those bids are set as accepted:true, they are considered an accepted_bid.

I want a function which returns all the docs (or a count of docs) that have one bid out of many (embedded arrays), which are owned by the logged in user.

The following does not work. I'm looking to have {{stats.count}} in the HTML file.

```
Template.dashboard.stats = function() {
        return Assignments.find({completed:true}, {
            transform: function(doc) {
                if(doc.bids) {
                var accepted_bid = _(doc.bids).findWhere({owner:Meteor.userId(),accepted:true});
                doc.bid = accepted_bid;
            }
            return doc;
        }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this would work but it returns a count:

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
    stats: function() {
    var assignments = Assignments.find({
        completed: true
    }, {
        transform: function(doc) {
            if (doc.bids) {
                var accepted_bid = _(doc.bids).findWhere({
                    owner: Meteor.userId(),
                    accepted: true
                });
                if(accepted_bid) doc.bid = accepted_bid;
            }
            return doc;
        }
    }).fetch();

    return _(assignments).chain().pluck("bid").compact().value().length;
    }
});
```

It can be used with {{stats}}